# Google Chrome extensions autoupdate

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As Google says [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html) you don't have to specify something if you host your Chrome app in Google Servers. But why all the extensions I analysed had this code in their manifest.json. Should I also write this code in my chrome extensions manifest?

```
"update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
```

As I said I will upload and share my app using chrome web store

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove "update_url" from manifest.json
Chrome automatically will update your extension from Web Store. So you should upload your extension to web Store.

Comment: Web store generates extension id

Comment: The field "update_url" is **automatically** set to  "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx" in your manifest.json when your app is installed from the Chrome Web Store (except if you have already defined it)